# Facebook Graph: Getting gender from all people who liked a post

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm trying to make some statics over a specific facebook page and for that I need to know the gender of all people who liked, commented and shared a specific post.

By following [this tutorial](http://nocodewebscraping.com/how-to-extract-data-from-facebook-page-competitor-analysis) I was able to get info of the users who interacted with the post, but for some reason I just can't get the gender of anyone.

The question is, what would be the best way to find out the gender of each user? Thank you!

Comment: You can't. The user need to grant you permission for that

Comment: Hm, gotcha... do you have any other suggestions related to data mining or web scraping which I could make good use of in this specific case?

Comment: No. You are not allowed to scrape Facebook

Comment: You might want to look into Insights.

Comment: Is it possible to access the insights of a page that is not mine?